# How to automate the f5 keystroke on a particular window

Tags: python, powershell, sendkeys, keystroke, keystrokes

I need to send the "f5" keystroke to a specific application once every 60 seconds. The application remains running in a fixed position on one of three screens.

Is there any way to automate this keystroke without having to remain in focus?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Is this a refresh for something? Maybe there is a better way than sending a keystroke.

Comment: Hi Joe,
Yes refresh the application.

Comment: What application exactly?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui
import time 

while True:
    pyautogui.press('f5')
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: This will work however it will not resolve the issue of refreshing the application (f5)  while it is not in focus.

Comment: which application? Linux, Windows?

Comment: Windows based application created using .net.

Comment: you can use pyautogui to click on the application, so F5 knows what its refreshing. ]